# How to call qml signal handler synchronously from cpp code from another thread?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, signals-slots

I know that normally you wouldn’t do what I’m asking. I understand that these two layers should be separate and connect via signal/slot mechanism, which maybe asynchronous if we deal with threads.

Understanding this, I still need to call qml signal handler synchronously from SG thread. Qml objects live in GUI thread, thus emitting a signal from SG thread (particularly from `updatePaintNode()` method) results in asynchronous event.

I have read docs and I have no problem calling qml function synchronously from cpp from another thread. For example:

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this, "myNiceQmlFunction", Qt::DirectConnection);
```

But imagine this:

```
//some.cpp

signal void callQmlHandler();

//some.qml
MyObject {
    onCallQmlHandler: {
        // do something right now
    }
}
```

I don’t know how to call `onCallQmlHandler` synchronously via `QMetaObject::invokeMethod`.
I don’t create qml object from code and at this point in cpp I don’t have access to qml component to look for its children, find `MyObject` there by name and call its handler (if it is possible). Anyways, this is not a beautiful way to do so.

I tried to find signal handler among QMetaObject methods, but it's not there. Nor it is in properties list (I checked just in case, because syntax of signal handlers is similar to property's one)

Does anyone know if I miss the right syntax to call signal handler via `QMetaObject::invokeMethod` or it is not possible at all? Any ideas?

Comment: Did you checked the [Connections](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-signals.html#using-the-connections-type) type? As stated, it "can receive any signal from its specified target."

Comment: If `invokeMethod(this, "myNiceQmlFunction", ...);` is a C++ sentence, and `this` a C++ object, how can `myNiceQmlFunction` be on QML?

Comment: @Smasho Type of <pre>this<code> is registered for qml with "qmlRegisterType", so it can be so pretty easy. I just declare in qml "function myNiceQmlFunction() {}" inside "Type" object.

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo could you please clarify? I don't see how qml  `Connections` type can help me call a handler from c++.

Comment: In your scenario there is a c++ signal and the handler is in QML. That's the code I see. And that is a use-case addressed by `Connections`, as @Smasho 's answer explains. By the way, signal-slot across threads are always `QueuedConnection`ed.

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo, signal/slot across threads are directly connected if you specify it explicitly with `DirectConnection`.

Comment: Yup but that's most of the time unsafe and by default they are queued. That was the meaning...my apologizes if I didn't specified that. Anyhow, the problem with `Connections` is that it is async or what else?

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo, If I got it right - `Connections` is a qml type that does in qml what `connect` does in cpp. So I don't see again how this makes any difference. Again, even if it could possibly solve the problem - I need to define a new qml object for this purpose. How is it better than defining a new qml function that already works for me? But it will not work, as you don't specify type of connection here. I checked @Smasho example with direct connection. It uses MetaObject finding methods. But as I stated in the question - signal handler is not listed in MetaObject methods, so you can't find it

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a C++ object to QML using its context.

```
qmlviewer.rootContext()->setContextProperty("backend", backend);
```

QML side:

```
Connections {
    target: backend
    onCallQmlHandler: {
        // do something right now
    }
}
```

When you emit `callQmlHandler` from backend object, you get the handler executed.
But `Connections` object may create queued connections, so you can implement your own `DirectConnections`. At the end of [this](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/53305-Direct-connection-in-QML) post you have an implementation.

However QML is excecuted by a QML engine, which I think is intended to be run by a single thread, so you may run into a bigger problem unless you really know what you are doing!